# JQuery validation only on button click and not onblur/onchange

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have  a simple form and a "Save" button. I want to validate the fields using JQuery validation plugin only when the user clicks the button. I do not want the error messages to appear or disappear until the user clicks on the save button.
Any solution?

Answer (score 7):

There is in-built functionality to toggle on/off the event you require ,

```
  onsubmit (default: true) : false //Disables form submit validation
  onfocusout: false //Disables onblur validation.
  onkeyup :false  //Disables onkeyup validation
  onclick : false //Disables onclick validation of checkboxes and radio buttons.
```

So, you could use it like ,

```
$(".selector").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```

**P.S**

You should thoroughly study the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#toptions).

Comment: Note that this needs to be done on the form object